# How can i use 'compressed texture' in openGL?

Tags: opengl, textures

In our project, we load so many 4K images in same time.
we want reduce upload time, which transfer texture to GPU.

My GPU is GTX 1080 ti.

I see using compressed texture make upload faster.

First i try to 'ASTC(Adaptive Scalable Texture compression)',  compress with 'mali Texture compression tool'.
i get 'compressed' file. 1~2mb jpg file (2048*2048 image) go to 456kb.

lower is my loader function.

```
  struct astc_header
{
    uint8_t magic[4];
    uint8_t blockdim_x;
    uint8_t blockdim_y;
    uint8_t blockdim_z;
    uint8_t xsize[3];           // x-size = xsize[0] + xsize[1] + xsize[2]
    uint8_t ysize[3];           // x-size, y-size and z-size are given in texels;
    uint8_t zsize[3];           // block count is inferred
};


int suppress_progress_counter = 0;
int perform_srgb_transform = 0;

#define MAGIC_FILE_CONSTANT 0x5CA1AB13

float load_astc_file(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!f)
    {
        printf("Failed to open file %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    astc_header hdr;
    size_t hdr_bytes_read = fread(&hdr, 1, sizeof(astc_header), f);
    if (hdr_bytes_read != sizeof(astc_header))
    {
        fclose(f);
        printf("Failed to read file %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    uint32_t magicval = hdr.magic[0] + 256 * (uint32_t)(hdr.magic[1]) + 65536 * (uint32_t)(hdr.magic[2]) + 16777216 * (uint32_t)(hdr.magic[3]);

    if (magicval != MAGIC_FILE_CONSTANT)
    {
        fclose(f);
        printf("File %s not recognized\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    int xdim = hdr.blockdim_x;
    int ydim = hdr.blockdim_y;
    int zdim = hdr.blockdim_z;

    if (xdim < 3 || xdim > 12 || ydim < 3 || ydim > 12 || (zdim < 3 && zdim != 1) || zdim > 12)
    {
        fclose(f);
        printf("File %s not recognized %d %d %d\n", filename, xdim, ydim, zdim);
        exit(1);
    }

    int xsize = hdr.xsize[0] + 256 * hdr.xsize[1] + 65536 * hdr.xsize[2];
    int ysize = hdr.ysize[0] + 256 * hdr.ysize[1] + 65536 * hdr.ysize[2];
    int zsize = hdr.zsize[0] + 256 * hdr.zsize[1] + 65536 * hdr.zsize[2];

    int xblocks = (xsize + xdim - 1) / xdim;
    int yblocks = (ysize + ydim - 1) / ydim;
    int zblocks = (zsize + zdim - 1) / zdim;
    int size = xblocks * yblocks * zblocks * 16;
    uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(size);
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fclose(f);
        printf("Ran out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    size_t bytes_to_read = xblocks * yblocks * zblocks * 16;
    size_t bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, bytes_to_read, f);
    fclose(f);
    if (bytes_read != bytes_to_read)
    {
        printf("Failed to read file %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    float compute_time;



    glFinish();
    CHECK_TIME_START;
    if (xdim == 12 && ydim == 12) {
        glCompressedTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_ASTC_12x12_KHR, xsize, ysize, 0, size, buffer);
    }
    else if (xdim == 10 && ydim == 10) {
        glCompressedTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_ASTC_10x10_KHR, xsize, ysize, 0, size, buffer);
    }
    else if (xdim == 8 && ydim == 8) {
        glCompressedTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_ASTC_8x8_KHR, xsize, ysize, 0, size, buffer);
    }
    else if (xdim == 6 && ydim == 6) {
        glCompressedTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_ASTC_6x6_KHR, xsize, ysize, 0, size, buffer);
    }
    else if (xdim == 5 && ydim == 5) {
        glCompressedTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_ASTC_5x5_KHR, xsize, ysize, 0, size, buffer);
    }
    else if (xdim == 4 && ydim == 4) {
        glCompressedTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_ASTC_4x4_KHR, xsize, ysize, 0, size, buffer);
    }
    glFinish();
    CHECK_TIME_END(compute_time);

    free(buffer);
    return compute_time;
}
```

sadly, it works perfect, but upload time is 40 times more than just upload jpg file.
jpg - 112ms, astc - 4124ms...

lower is part of load jpg function.

```
    glFinish();
    CHECK_TIME_START;
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    glFinish();
    CHECK_TIME_END(compute_time);
```

in some pages, astc is more faster than no compressed image. it's wrong?
i think glCompressedTexImage2D slower than glTexImage2D. it's right?

Next, I try ARB with this document.
https://www.oldunreal.com/editing/s3tc/ARB_texture_compression.pdf

but it perfectly not work....
saved file(compressed file) is just 4kb. original is 16MB... of course not work.

I can't fine the example or tutorial for using compressed texture.
please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Compressed load should be noticeably faster, not massively slower, due to much smaller amount of data being transferred to GPU.

Most likely issue is that timing the specific GL call is giving you an error. The driver may be blocking/yielding for some reason.  Try timing the whole load-up section with just the code change.  Your Buffer Object may mean that there's some syncing in one case vs the other?

Other possible issue is if there is some format conversion / other feature enabled that's causing it to decompress. So check if it's also doing auto mipmap generation or flipping the co-ords from top-left-bottom-left[0,0], or some quality option in your driver (make sure things are disabled / application-controlled in your NVidia control panel).